# Can't upload PDF file with file size of 1MB or higher in odoo-12

Tags: pdf, odoo, odoo-12

Hi I'm having this problem when I am trying to upload a PDF Template, my localhost give me a message **"Trying to reconnect"** and then quickly followed by **"You are back online"** after uploading a PDF file, but the file is not uploaded my PDF file size is 1 MB

Comment: try to get log for that part.

Comment: It might happen when in because of nginx configuration.
Increase the size in **nginx** and set **client_max_body_size** limit.
Odoo's default limit is **25 MB** so it should allow uploading this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Nginx.

Then it can be solved by adding a new line in your nginx.conf file and then restart Nginx.

Set it in HTTP block which affects all server blocks (virtual hosts).
In Ubuntu nginx.conf file can be found here /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
http {
...
client_max_body_size 100M;
}
```

My issue has been solved in this way.